# Why isn't the argument assignable only when we don't know exactly what type from the union it is?

Tags: typescript

I made a straightforward snippet illustrating the problem:

```
type Mono<T> = T extends void ? [] : [T];
type MyUnion = { hi: string } | { hello: string } | { bye: number } | void;
type MyMono = Mono<MyUnion>;

function asd(...args: MyMono) {}

function qwe(u: MyUnion) {
  asd(u); // Error!
  /**
   * (parameter) u: MyUnion
      Argument of type '[MyUnion]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[] | [{ hi: string; }] | [{ hello: string; }] | [{ bye: number; }]'.
        Type '[MyUnion]' is not assignable to type '[{ hi: string; }]'.
          Type 'MyUnion' is not assignable to type '{ hi: string; }'.
            Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ hi: string; }'.ts(2345)
   */
}

const a = { hi: "" };
const b = { hello: "" };
const c = { bye: 1 };

// All works
asd();
qwe();
asd(a);
qwe(a);
asd(b);
qwe(b);
asd(c);
qwe(c);
```

I can see that the types are different but cannot understand why all possible values are assignable to both (if we know the value upfront) but not in the inner function call case where we don't know what value was passed as an argument.

Btw, the `void` in the union is not the problem as the same happens if I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

**The reason why the inner function call gives the error:**

`asd` function parameters described as union of tuples: `[{ hi: string }] | [{ hello: string }] | [{ bye: number }] | []`.

`u` parameter in `qwe` function typed as `MyUnion` which in turns resolves to `{ hi: string } | { hello: string } | { bye: number } | void`.

When TS check assignability of `u` type to `asd` parameters type it represents  type of `u` as tuple like this `[{ hi: string } | { hello: string } | { bye: number } | void]`. And finally, type `[{ hi: string } | { hello: string } | { bye: number } | void]` is not assignable to `[{ hi: string }] | [{ hello: string }] | [{ bye: number }] | []`, that's why you got the error.

Conclusion: Types in TS doesn't change dynamically. If you declare `u` type as `MyUnion` then no matter which type would be passed to `qwe` call, type of `u` would be `MyUnion` anyway. That's why TS doesn't need to wait for the outer function call to make type checks for the inner function call.

**The reason why separate function call has no errors:**

The main rule - TS always makes type checks between two entities: what is required and what is used.

In your cases:

```
const a = { hi: "" };
const b = { hello: "" };
const c = { bye: 1 };

// asd requires parameters of type [{ hi: string }] | [{ hello: string }] | [{ bye: number }] | []
// qwe requires parameters of type { hi: string } | { hello: string } | { bye: number } | void 

// All works
asd(); // void type is assignable to []
qwe(); // void type is assignable to void
asd(a); // ...
qwe(a); // ...
asd(b); // ...
qwe(b); // ...
asd(c); // ...
qwe(c); // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was really expecting it would work since we only pass the item to `asd` and it's the runtime which wraps it into an array. But I guess I can see the limitation here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be at `Mono<T>`.

```js
type Mono<T> = T[];
type MyUnion = { hi: string } | { hello: string } | { bye: number } | void;
type MyMono = Mono<MyUnion>;

function asd(...args: MyMono) {}

function qwe(u: MyUnion) {
  asd(u); // No error!
}

const a = { hi: "" };
const b = { hello: "" };
const c = { bye: 1 };

// All works
asd();
qwe();
asd(a);
qwe(a);
asd(b);
qwe(b);
asd(c);
qwe(c);
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gOzgHgCoD4oF4qoNoC6A3ALABQoksIAqggJaLZQDeUAFvQFxQDOwAJ3oIA5lAC%20UAD6sOEADby4PfkNETpsgEYgIPBAFcAtlogCNMgG5x6AE1IVw0GCHhJmblC7qME6B%20QAZgYIAMbAvlAAhry2ABQAdElRAiK8PC6eAJSs4uRBIeGRAI4A7hBxBhm0DIg5LORQ0bGVWURQAPQdUABycFBmAnACAITkeWTkoYj80cxsnDwAREsSDtMIs1rzcorKUCtrUzPAUKE7OnpQAIxHk2RdUACCilClwwDWvOQx8W3kZQq-zIvziUWBgLBwNBWgh5TisIcoNCcIqKKIQA)

Comment: Thanks for the answerm but the intent of that type is to be exactly that: either an array of 1 or 0 elements. This will limit the amount of args I can pass to asd. If you go back into my snippet and try to give more than 1 arg to asd call it will error. Likewise, if you remove the `void` from the union then the 1st two calls I left there will also error out. I understand how your solution fixes the problem but I lose the feature I needed for type-checking...

Comment: Also, if` `MyUnion` wasn't a union type then that declaration would work just fine, which means this is a problem caused by the type distribution on the conditional type `Mono`